# Share network to multiple other ethernet networks

Tags: networking, windows-8, network-shares, home-sharing

I was wondering whether it is possible to share a network connection to multiple other networks in Windows. I've been able to share it with one other network, but it does not allow me to share it with multiple.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jAMlgLo.png]

I want to share "Ethernet" to "Ethernet 2" and "Wi-fi"

Is that possible in Windows 8?